# jQuery img add doesn't show

Tags: jquery, image, click, prepend

I have the following jQuery code:

```
$('#foo').click(function ()  {
    var loading = $('<img id="loading" src="images/loader.gif" alt="loading" />');
    $('#stars').prepend(loading);
    alert('WAIT');
});

$('#bar').click(function ()  {
     $('#stars').empty();
});
```

When first clicking `#foo` the image is being shown in my browser window. After clicking `#bar` and then `#foo` again the image is not being shown.

I use Chrome and also use the `Inspect Element` tool and I can see in the code that the `img` tag was added in `#stars` when clicking for the second time `#foo`. But no `img` is being shown in the browser window.

Any ideas why? Should I use the `live()` function perhaps, but how?

Comment: [Works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/yLZeQ/).

Comment: I've tried out an example of your code on jsfiddle and it works there:http://jsfiddle.net/VewBu/

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work fine for me.

See a demo I put together here: http://jsfiddle.net/uWfW7/1/

I'm unable to test this in Chrome right now but it's working for me in FF5. Alternatively, instead of re-creating the image object every time you could simply show/hide the image as reqired.

**HTML**

```
<div id="image"><img src="[...] alt="text"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#image{display:none;}
```

**JS**

```
$('#foo').click(function(){$('#image').show()})
$('#bar').click(function(){$('#image').hide()})
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/t5QJg/

Comment: Did my answer help you @Luzhin? Remember to accept the answer if this is the case :-)

Answer (score 0):

it seems to work fine, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/84Nj3/1/

Maybe there is something different in your code that causes the problem.

Comment: Nope it does not show up in your fiddle. (I'm using Chromium 52.0.2743.116).